# Spring MVC-Request method 'POST' not supported: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following warning: 
Request method 'POST' not supported.

Controller method:

```
@Controller
public class UserServiceController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public String login(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(requestParams.values());
    loginService.userAuthentication(requestParams.get("loginuname"), requestParams.get("loginpassword"));

    System.out.println("Before return");
    return "static/profile.html";
}
}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />
```

index.html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){
    document.login.submit();
}
</script>
<div id="login" class="login">   
<form action="http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/login" name="login" method="post">
      <input type="text" value = "Email" name="loginuname" id="loginuname" class="loginbasetxt">

      <input type="text" value="Password" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" class="loginbasetxt">
      <img src="static/img/tb-login-button.png" onclick="submitForm()"/>
</form>  
</div>
```

However, **if i would change the method=RequestMethod.GET and correspondingly at login page then it would work.**

Please note, problem is at **return "static/profile.html";**

FYI location of profile.html is WEB-INF/static/

Thanks!!

Comment: Get that warning where? And are you submitting the login information as request parameters in the `POST` or as a form?

Comment: are you sure your form's URL is correct and action attribute is action="POST"?

Comment: Please post the http form, the request that is sended, as well as the annotations next to the class keyword of your controller class.

Comment: could you please add some more code of Controller and jsp file or stack trace of error if you are getting on your console.

Comment: @chrylis getting HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported, on the browser.Yes, for the second query.

Comment: @isah yes, it is working for GET method

Comment: @Ashish there is just this, 21 Jan, 2014 5:48:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported on the console.

Comment: @Saint please post your complete Dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml file It seams that error is in your action value of  <form action="http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/login"> tag

Comment: The problem got resolved with redirect/static/profile.html

Answer (score 3):

When you `POST` a form to an HTTP server, the form's contents aren't sent as query parameters; instead, the form is (usually) uploaded as an entity of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Instead of using `@RequestParam` in your method, define a Java class that has fields corresponding to the form fields, and use `@ModelAttribute FormClass form`.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
return "forward:/static/profile.html";
```