# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported . Technology Used . Spring MVC and Spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC (4.0.0.RELEASE) and Spring Security (3.2.4.RELEASE).

When i am trying to submit a page i am getting "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported ." Error.

**`web.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>ProAccounting</display-name>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>proaccounting</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>proaccounting</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
             /WEB-INF/DataSource.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**proaccounting-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pro94tek.*" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"></bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <!-- ref bean="marshallingConverter" /-->
                <ref bean="atomConverter"  />
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
                 <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
    </bean-->

    <bean id="atomConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/atom+xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>


 <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.sai.tfms.entity.SaiAgroUserEntity</value>
                <value>com.sai.tfms.entity.TFMAccountEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property-->

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
             <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" 
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/proaccounting" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="examXmlView"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

     <!-- bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean-->

    <mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/companyRegister**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
         <intercept-url pattern="/company/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/index" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/index?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select userid,password, enabled from proaccounting.pro_login_user where userid=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from proaccounting.user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**companybasicinfo.jsp This is the jsp from which i am trying to submit the page.**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="pro" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/css/custom-sky-forms.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/css/sky-forms-ie8.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- CSS Theme -->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themes/default.css" id="style_color">

    <!-- CSS Customization -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
 <div class="container content">  
 <div class="panel panel-sea">
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>Company Details</h3>
</div>
 <div class="panel-body">

    <pro:form   action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/companyRegister"  commandName="company" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sky-form1" class="sky-form">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <header>Trade Details</header>
    <fieldset>                  
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">

                      <pro:input type="text" path="legalName" placeholder="Company Legal Name"/>
                      <p class="note note-error"><pro:errors path="legalName"/></p>
                  </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">

                      <pro:input type="text" path="companyName" placeholder="Company Display Name"/>
                      <p class="note note-error"><pro:errors path="companyName"/></p>
                  </label>
              </section>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="select">
                            <pro:select path="lineofBusiness">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>Line of Business</option>
                                <option value="design">Retails</option>
                                <option value="development">Manufacturer</option>
                                <option value="illustration">Accounting</option>
                                <option value="branding">Software</option>
                            </pro:select>
                      <i><p class="note note-error"><pro:errors path="lineofBusiness"/></p>
                            </i>
                     </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="select">
                            <pro:select path="organizationType">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>Organization Type</option>
                                <option value="design">Retails</option>
                                <option value="development">Manufacturer</option>
                                <option value="illustration">Accounting</option>
                                <option value="branding">Software</option>
                            </pro:select>
                             <i><p class="note note-error"><pro:errors path="organizationType"/></p>
                            </i>
                     </label>
              </section>
          </div>          
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="textarea">
                       <textarea rows="3" name="comment" placeholder="Organization Description"></textarea>
                   </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label for="file" class="input input-file">
                       <div class="button"><input type="file" name="file" multiple onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value">Browse</div><input type="text" placeholder="Company Logo" readonly>
                   </label>
              </section>
          </div>                    
      </fieldset>  
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
<header>Registered Office Address</header>
    <fieldset>                  
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="textarea">
                       <textarea rows="3" name="addressline1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></textarea>
                   </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="textarea">
                       <textarea rows="3" name="addressline2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></textarea>
                   </label>
              </section>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="select">
                            <select name="state">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>State</option>
                                <option value="design">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="development">Arunachal</option>
                                <option value="illustration">Karnatka</option>
                                <option value="branding">Tamilnadu</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="select">
                            <select name="district">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>District</option>
                                <option value="design">District 1</option>
                                <option value="design">District 2</option>
                                <option value="design">District 3</option>
                                <option value="design">District 4</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
          </div>          
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="select">
                            <select name="city">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>City</option>
                                <option value="design">City 1</option>
                                <option value="design">City 2</option>
                                <option value="design">City 3</option>
                                <option value="design">City 4</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">
                      <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code">
                  </label>
              </section>
          </div>  
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">
                      <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
                  </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">

                      <input type="text" name="fax" placeholder="Fax">
                  </label>
              </section>
          </div> 
      </fieldset>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
<header>Postal Address</header>

    <fieldset> 

          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                 <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="sameaddress" checked><i></i>Same as Registered Office</label>
              </section>

          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="textarea">
                       <textarea rows="3" name="paddressline1" placeholder="Address Line 1"></textarea>
                   </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="textarea">
                       <textarea rows="3" name="paddressline2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></textarea>
                   </label>
              </section>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="select">
                            <select name="pstate">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>State</option>
                                <option value="design">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="development">Arunachal</option>
                                <option value="illustration">Karnatka</option>
                                <option value="branding">Tamilnadu</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="select">
                            <select name="pdistrict">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>District</option>
                                <option value="design">District 1</option>
                                <option value="design">District 2</option>
                                <option value="design">District 3</option>
                                <option value="design">District 4</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
          </div>          
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                    <label class="select">
                            <select name="pcity">
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>City</option>
                                <option value="design">City 1</option>
                                <option value="design">City 2</option>
                                <option value="design">City 3</option>
                                <option value="design">City 4</option>
                            </select>
                            <i></i>
                     </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">
                      <input type="text" name="pzipcode" placeholder="Zip Code">
                  </label>
              </section>
          </div>  
          <div class="row">
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">
                      <input type="text" name="pphonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
                  </label>
              </section>
              <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="input">

                      <input type="text" name="pfax" placeholder="Fax">
                  </label>
              </section>
          </div> 
      </fieldset>
      </div>
<div class="col-md-5">
 <fieldset><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
     <footer>
     <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="error">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-u" value="Add Company"/>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default" onclick="window.history.back();">Back</button>
                        </footer>
  </fieldset>
</div>
      </pro:form>
</div> 
 </div>
</div> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
<!-- Checkout Form -->
<script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<!-- Order Form -->
<script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/plugins/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/sky-forms-ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <script src="assets/plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

**CompanyController.java. Corresponding Controller.**

```
    package com.pro94tek.proaccounting.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.pro94tek.proaccounting.modal.Company;



@Controller
public class CompanyController {


        @ModelAttribute("company")
        public Company getLoginForm() {
            return new Company();
        }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/companybasicinfo"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

      ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
      model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
      model.addObject("message", "This is Company page!");
      model.setViewName("company/companybasicinfo");

      return model;

    }

    @PostAuthorize(value = "")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/companyRegister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerCompany( @Valid Company company,
                        BindingResult result) {

      ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
      try{
              modelView.addObject("msg","Company Registered Successfully");
              if(result.hasErrors())
                  modelView.setViewName("company/companybasicinfo?errors");

              else
                  modelView.setViewName("company/companybasicinfo?msg");
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return modelView;

    }

}
```

In Log i am just seeing following message

Aug 12, 2014 3:58:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

Can any one help out where the wrong i am doing

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if i need to provide any extra info

Even tried in following way

Comment: Even tried by modifying form tag in following way                <pro:form   action="companyRegister"  commandName="company" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sky-form1" class="sky-form">

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC-Request method 'POST' not supported: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258294/spring-mvc-request-method-post-not-supported-org-springframework-web-servlet)